# Python: Creating new lists inside while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So in my approach to First-improvement local search I have encountered a point in which I can't seem to move forward. That if-statement and the variables assignment are driving me nuts. When I "debug" it with prints I can't get to see what happens and I need someone to shed light on this matter.

```
def main():
    start = time.time()
    matrix = [[5, 3], [2, 7], [9, 1], [0, 6], [8, 4]]
    initial = [3, 1, 4, 5, 2]
    combs = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 2],[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
    i = 0
    while time.time() - start < 1:
        best = initial
        while i < 5:
            sol = best
            fBest = fMax(best, matrix)

            sol[combs[i][0]], sol[combs[i][1]] = sol[combs[i][1]], sol[combs[i][0]]

            fCurrent = fMax(sol, matrix)
            if fCurrent < fBest:
                best = sol
                i = 0
                continue
            i = i + 1
    print(best)
    return best
```

Output of this is a infinite loop in which best variable updates weirdly.

Seems like the mistake is with `sol` and `best`. I need them to be new, independent lists.

Comment: What is the problem you are having with the current implementation ?

Comment: Those variable assignments (best = initial, best = sol), doesn't seem to work as I want. I think the mistake is with the second while (that continue), but i'm not sure.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work as I want" doesn't let us know what you're trying to fix. What **visibly** goes wrong? What happens, and what did you expect to happen differently?

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting lines like `best = initial` and `sol = best` to create new, independent lists. They don't. You should read up on [how variables and variable assignment actually work in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Well, as I say in the last line, the output is an infinite loop. Let's start fixing that.

Comment: Seems like you are right and I need new independent lists. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just adding `[:]` when assigning the new lists:

```
best = initial[:]
sol = best[:]
best = sol[:]
```

Adding `[:]` creates a copy of the list instead of referencing it, that is why I couldn't compare `best` and `sol`: They were both always referencing `initial`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

input("Press Enter to continue...")

In the first/second while to print the variables and this way you can debug it step by step.